# Unexpected Behaviour with and w/o Volatile Keyword

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

```
public class ThreadVolatilePerfectExample2 {
  public static boolean  stop = false; // not volatile
  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
      Thread testThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
              int i = 1;
              while(!stop){
                  i++;
              }
              System.out.println("Thread stop i="+ i);
           }
         };
         testThread.start();
         Thread.sleep(1);
         stop = true;
         System.out.println("now, in main thread stop is: " + stop);
         testThread.join();
     }
 }
```

Marking stop volatile or not is not affecting the output, it is only affecting If I have increased the sleep time.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?

Comment: Expected behaviour is thread should only stop, if stop variable is volatile

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Java not see the updated value from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135870/why-does-java-not-see-the-updated-value-from-another-thread)

Comment: If not able to answer the question , please don't downvote it

Comment: "not affecting the output" what is the output? Does the thread stop?

Answer (score 0):

> Marking stop volatile or not is not affecting the output, it is only
>   affecting If I have increased the sleep time.

Not using volatile doesn't mean that threads sharing a same variable will always  have a not updated value.

The idea is that according the case, it may and to prevent from  having a not updated variable in one thread, you should declare the variable with the `volatile` modifier.

In your case, you don't see the problem as `testThread` has probably not run yet, so the value of the `stop` variable was not initialized yet in the memory of this thread.

Increasing the argument of `sleep()` allows the current thread to be paused.
  `testThread` can so run and initialize the value of the variable to `false` in its own memory.
Then, the main thread is resumed and set `stop` to true :`stop = true;` so `testThread` doesn't see modification on `stop`.

Comment: Got something from ur answer