# Unable to understand threading behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging

```
package safety.publishing;

public class PublicStaticPublishing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new ReadRunnable()).start();
        new Thread(new WriteRunnable()).start();
    }

}

class A {
    public static int i = 0;
}

class ReadRunnable implements Runnable {
    int cache = A.i;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            if (A.i != cache) {
                System.out.println("cache miss " + A.i + " " + cache);
                cache = A.i;
            } else {
                // System.out.println("cache hit"); 
            }
        }
    }
}

class WriteRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i =0; i<1000; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            A.i++;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a reader thread and a writer thread. When the 'println' statement in the else block of ReadRunnable.run() method is commented as shown above, for reasons I can't comprehend the 'println' statement in the if block doesn't execute as well. The console stays blank indefinitely.

However, if I uncomment the 'println' in the else block, then both the println statements in the if and the else block prints as shown below.

```
cache hit
cache hit
cache hit
cache hit
cache hit
cache hit
cache hit
cache hit
cache hit
cache hit
cache miss 222 221
cache hit
```

What am I doing wrong? Help me understand whats going on.

Comment: Printlns can cause the ordering of execution to change, just like any other operation, especially slow ones.  There are no rules, no guarantees.  It's also allowed to work differently depending on whether it's Tuesday.

Comment: @LouisWasserman clarification, the question is not about ordering.  I understand that ordering is not deterministic. 

What I notice is that commenting the else block println, as in the code, disables the if block println as well. Why does that happen?

Comment: What I find weird is that cache should be the value of A.i at the start, but its not like cache is being updated unless it enters the if block. Is it due to volatility? All the updates of A.i  are on the write thread but the read thread has not seen the updates?

Comment: apparently the change is  visibile  if I uncomment the println in the else block. @BIBOOunit1998X

Comment: Yeah, i did some extra print statements and I believe it is due to volatility of A.i. The read thread is not able to see updates, but if extra print statements are added either in the else block or outside the if-else, it will see the updates eventually. But if you make the variable volatile it will behave correctly and see all updates even if you comment out the else block

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21135976/16034206 I think its something like this. Based on the answer here, my understanding is that the compiler detects that no changes made to A.i or cache, so the thread doesnt bother to read it even if the value is changed later (or the compiler optimizes it away?). but with your extra print statements, it accesses the value of A.i and can detect that the value changes, causing the if-statement to evaulate to true

Comment: Other comments above have answered your question, but please, please, please, do yourself a favor, and _never_ write an empty `catch` block. If you're pretty sure that the exception can  never happen, then at least put a `println` call or a `log` call in the catch block that will provide you with a clue if it turns out you were wrong.

Comment: Hope, this is just for testing and never ever goes into production code? Use higher level constructs in Java’s concurrency package! See https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrency or specifically https://www.baeldung.com/java-countdown-latch for your case

Comment: Not for production @StefanHaberl was just exploring visibility topic.

Answer (score 0):

When you uncomment the `println` statement in the else block, it introduces a delay due to the output operation, and during this time, the writer thread (`WriteRunnable`) has a chance to update the value of `A.i`. Consequently, when the `cache` is compared with `A.i` in the if statement, depending upon whether the writer thread had a chance or not to update `A.i`, the "cache miss" or "cache hit" message is printed.

However, when you comment out the `println` in the else block, there is no delay introduced, and the loop runs very quickly. In this case, the value of `A.i` might not have changed by the time the `if` statement is executed, leading to the else block being executed consistently, making the console stay blank indefinitely.

Comment: To assume that context swtich happens upon invocation of println only ... may be little too organized to be true.